# Bondi $k$-factor: how to reconcile spacetime intervals?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime

I'm studying about the k-factor (ref. following diagram)

[image]

Let the events of sending first and second light pulses be $P$ and $Q$. In $A$'s frame, the time separation between the events is $T$ and the space separation is $0$ (both pulses sent from the same point). In $B$'s frame, however, the time separation becomes $kT$, while the space separatio is still $0$ (both pulses received at the same point).

Since my fundamentals aren't clear, I'm a bit confused on how to reconcile the spacetime interval between $P$ and $Q$ in both frames. It'll be $\Delta s^2_A=-c^2T^2$ for $A$ and $\Delta s^2_B=-c^2k^2T^2$ for $B$. Isn't the spacetime interval supposed to be invariant?

Comment: In B’s frame wouldn’t it look like A has sent pulses from two different points? You are mixing up frames.

Comment: @FellowTraveller: Ah yes, you're completely right. My bad

Comment: essentially B’s frame would be identical to the one you’ve shown. When you do these calculations, you are doing them in **one** frame of reference. So find both the space-time intervals from just the image you’ve shown.

Comment: @FellowTraveller: Another minor clarification if you don't mind - why is the time separation of received signals (as measured in $B$ frame) proportional to the time separation of the sent signals (as measured in $A$ frame)? How to derive that fact assuming that we don't know of Lorentz transformations yet?

Comment: Look at the intersection of the light lines. Imagine A is sending a pulse every second. The ratio between the length of the lines in B frame to that in A frame is constant. Namely $k$. This means for every second in A, $k$ seconds have passed in B (according to A of course).

Comment: The k-factor is the Doppler factor... the ratio of the reception period to the emission period.